# Why are some questions that were closed as not "real" being edited months later?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[Alternative good-looking desktop for Ubuntu [closed]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2004/alternative-good-looking-desktop-for-ubuntu) is a recent example. It was closed as not being a real question on Sep 8 '11. I feel that editing closed questions without intending to have them re-opened bumps them, perhaps unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Take a look the revisions.](https://askubuntu.com/posts/2004/revisions)

It was part of a cleanup to fix the [untagged](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/untagged) mess.